# merge two images (one image is transparent without face , second image is only face which coming from sdcard)

Tags: android

I have a two image one image is containing body without face and one image contain with face only...

now I want to merge this two images.... the first image which contain only body without face is in that the face is transparent.....

So how can I detect that transparent area and place face over there in transparent area?

I am combining two images with below code.. but it is not proper way to place face over transparent area

My code is given below,

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
    Bitmap cs = null;

    int width, height = 0;

    if (c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) {
        width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    } else {
        width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
        height = c.getHeight();
    }

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 0f, 0f, null);

    return cs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge two or more images in android by using Canvas its simple to merge image by using below code,
first create bitmap for particular image which you want to merge it.

get X and Y axis position for which area you want to merge images.

```
    mComboImage = new Canvas(mBackground);

   mComboImage.drawBitmap(c, x-axis position in f, y-axis position in f, null);

    mComboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null);
    mComboImage.drawBitmap(s, 200f, 200f, null);


    mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBackground);
    Bitmap mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable)mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
```

set this new bitmap in imageview. 
imageView.setImageBitmap(mNewSaving);

Here in this method two image bitmap combine in one bitmap which return bitmap of new merge image.Also save this image on sdcard.As  below code

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
    Bitmap cs = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
      width = c.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
      width = s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight() + s.getHeight(); 
    } 

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, new Matrix(), null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, new Matrix(), null);

    // this is an extra bit I added, just incase you want to save the new image somewhere and then return the location.

    return cs; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper way to merge two bitmaps:

```
    public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap topImage, Bitmap bottomImage) {
        Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight(), bottomImage.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bottomImage, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(topImage, 0, 0, null);
        return overlay;
    }
```